# How do I get the type of an object in code?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

How do I figure out the type of an object in C?  My goal with this is to create a linked-list container in C.

Let's assume I have a function that takes a void pointer:

```
...
Foo *f;
f = Allocate(f);
...

void *Allocate(void *item)
{
  return malloc(sizeof(f.GetType));
}
```

How do I make the above syntax possible?

Comment: 1) Why do you need to know the type to create a linked list?
2) You explicitly don't want to use c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. A `void *` pointer, is just a pointer to the memory, nothing more, no more information is attached to it. It's impossible to do what you are asking, you can't know how many bytes to `malloc`.

That's why, the [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/) function from `stdlib.h` library takes as a parameter
the `size` in bytes of each array element. If what you suggested was possible, then
`qsort` wouldn't need such a parameter.

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
...
Foo *f;
f = Allocate(f, sizeof(Foo));
...

void *Allocate(void *item, size_t size)
{
  return malloc(size);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, there's no cross platform way to find out the underlying type of a void*, since the type information is not stored in the object. In C++ this feature has been added for objects.

You could of course implement it yourself for your own objects by - for example - storing the size of every object in the object itself, but for system objects there is no built in way.

Comment: By the way, I am working with Microsoft Compiler v9.0 (Visual Studio 2008), cross-platform code is not a priority for my project.

Comment: Considering the work involved to tag and track all types you want the above syntax for, I'd look for another way to do it. The usual way to do it in C in your example is to pass sizeof(Foo) to Allocate instead since you know the type at call time.

Answer (score 1):

It is just not possible to get the `type` using a `void *` to that object. If you can calculate the size of `Foo` before calling `Allocate()`, then get the size and pass it as a parameter to `Allocate()`, else you should make `Foo` visible inside `Allocate()` to find the size.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in C is to create your own type system where you include typeinfo to the types that you create. That is what has been done for instance in Objective-C. In C, all types are just a series of bytes, when you allocate memory you are allocating just bytes, what you use those bytes for is of no concern to the C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The (arguable) beauty of C is that it doesn't do this. A void pointer is just an address that could point to *anything*. You could either create your own object system (structures with a "type" field and a "data" field is a simple way). From your implementation, it might also be possible to stick an `allocate` function into the `Foo` structure (assuming that it is) which knows how to allocate itself (the type is known here).

Answer (score 1):

```
void *Allocate(void *item)
{
  return malloc(sizeof(f.GetType));
}
```

It is impossible. ISO C language does't supply any facility to get the type info through variable. Gcc's extensions contains an operator called 'typeof', it could get the type info from a real type. such as:

```
typeof (x[0](1))
int a; typeof (a) b; b = a;
```

but even though typeof also could not get the real type info from a void pointer. the code below could not be compiled succesfully:

```
void *Allocate(typeof(*item) *item)
{
  return malloc(sizeof(*item));
}
```